# Open a new Chrome window in Incognito mode from terminal

Tags: terminal, google-chrome

I can open a url specifying 'chrome browser' from terminal

```
open -a 'Google chrome' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

How to open it in an incognito mode?

Answer (score 25):

Use something like:

`open -a "Google Chrome" --args --incognito "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"`

Google Chrome accepts `--incognito` as a command-line option.  To pass that option to the application via `open`, specify it after the `--args` flag.

If Chrome isn't already open (since this was not specified whether the original questioner needed to launch it fresh or if it was already running), `-n` is also needed to start a fresh instance.

In general, `man open` is your friend.

Comment: what is -a for?

Comment: The argument to `-a` specifies the application to open.  You can check the man page for `open` (via `man open`) for all the options.

Comment: the reason this works sometimes:  chrome isn't already running, so it's being passed the arg in a form that works.    the reason -n is needed is when chrome is already running the incog arg doesnt apply (since it's not being launched).    (and downvote)

Comment: `open -n /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --incognito` just opens chrome without having to specify a url.

Answer (score 23):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on the above answer, but wanted to add that if you don't have an incognito window open already, you need to add the -n flag to open a new incognito instance.  So, using the above example would be:

```
open -na "Google Chrome" --args --incognito "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
```

Comment: this is the most usable solution - sadly, if chrome is running already it DOES open a NEW copy of chrome (so startup time isn't great).   it would be lovely if chrome offered a url prefix to always open a url in incog... ;)

Comment: the "comment above" is an answer that might change position if your answer is better. I would also reconsider mentioning it at all

Comment: Two years on, it should be pointed out to @keen that Chrome likely keeps incognito and "cognito" windows in separate processes. When you think about it, this makes all the sense in the world: you wouldn't want your incognito data in the same process and subject to hacking/bugs, and getting leaked into a "cognito" window, or from one incognito window into another. It becomes a LOT harder to leak if they are in different address spaces!

Comment: PS: to @keen@2019, what's it like in The Beforetimes?

Comment: @MarkGerolimatos in normal operations they'd be children of the same parent process.   in my memory of 2019 when I tested this, it spun up a new parent process each time.     in 2021 testing, it doesnt, however - each time I trigger it (in a simple test case) it opens an incog window under the existing parent, and adds a new tab to the existing incog if it's already open.    

and that pretty much summarizes my 2019, 2020, and 2021..............

Answer (score 1):

Use `open chrome --args --incognito "websitename.com"` to open it in icognito mode

Comment: How does this answer differ from the highest voted answer already posted?

Comment: I'm not using -a flag. I wrote the answer because top voted answer didn't worked for me.

Comment: `-a` is the application specifier which forces the named application to open if it's not the default.  It has no bearing on the arguments sent to the application itself.

Comment: Without the `-a` _option_, your answer errors out with: `The file /Users/me/chrome does not exist.`